# Avoiding disposing system-defined Pen and Brush instances

Tags: winforms, gdi+, idisposable, system.drawing

I understand it is best practise to call Dispose() on instances of [Pen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.aspx) and [Brush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush.aspx), except if they've been set to the system-predefined values (eg. [System.Drawing.Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brushes.aspx),  [System.Drawing.Pens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pens.aspx) or [System.Drawing.SystemBrushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systembrushes.aspx))

Trying to dispose a system-defined resource results in an exception being thrown.

It doesn't appear to be obvious how you can detect (apart from wrapping the Dispose() call in a try/catch) whether one of these resources is referencing a system-defined or user-defined value.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

There is no requirement to call `Dispose`. The purpose of garbage collection is to eliminate these kinds of requirements.

One of the main purposes of `IDisposable` is to allow a class to clean up unmanaged resources in resource-limited environments. If you do not call the dispose method, the unmanaged resouces of the class will be cleaned up once the object is finialized and disposed during garbage collection.

If you "must" call dispose and you do not know if the brush instance is a "system-" or a "normal-" brush then you will have to use a try...catch block.

- It is not needed to call dispose on `SystemBrushes` and `SystemPens` because the GDI+ Library will take care of these resources.
- Okay to dispose of `SystemFonts` and `SystemIcons`.

The **Remarks** section of the class will make note of if there is a requirement to call the `Dispose` method. *If the Remarks section recommends to call the Dispose method, then I will do it.*

In general, I do not call dispose on pens and brushes. If I have a graphic-intensive application or class then I will cache instances of the pens and brushes I need. I use them throughout the life of the application or class. If I didn't do this then graphics painting performance will suffer trying to create and dispose all those ojects so many times and so frequently. (Hm...now that I think about it, performance is probably why we cannot dispose of SystemBrushes and SystemPens, yet can dispose of SystemFonts and SystemIcons. Even the framework caches SystemBrushes and SystemPens.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, however I think it needs clarifying that the GC will only clean up unmanaged resources if you have a finalizer declared - it doesn't automatically call your Dispose() method. Applications can pre-empt the GC by calling Dispose() which should then allow it to be GC'd sooner.

Otherwise, I suspect you are right and try/catch is the only option if there is no other way of knowing what the brush/pen was set to.

Comment: Note that nearly all GDI+ based classes implement the `IDisposable` interface because of their use of unmanaged resources. Therefore, in regards to this question and answer, `Dispose(disposing=False)` will always be called through the `Finalize` method. Regardless, there is still no requirement to call `Dispose`.

Comment: The framework automatically calls the `Dispose` methods of any created `SystemBrushes` and `SystemPens` objects when the GDI+ library is shut-down.

Comment: I did not use the word "automatically". I left out the details because this is not part of the question/answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the remarks in this case are incomplete.  Look at the sample code in the documentation -- it does explicitly call Dispose, as it should.

Actually, that first statement works as a general rule.  If remarks were that complete, wouldn't we have less need for sites like this one? :)

Comment: @DavidGardiner: Will you consider unaccepting this answer, so that it is no longer pinned to the top of the page, waiting to mislead ever more readers?

Answer (score 34):

This is an old question I know, but I've been doing some research into resource leaks involving GDI objects, and almost every statement in the accepted answer is false. In the interests of accuracy for later readers who find this question via a search, as I did:

> There is no requirement to call Dispose.

This statement is misleading. Though technically you can get away with not calling `Dispose`, it is an extremely poor practice to not dispose of a brush or pen **that you own** once you're done with it.

The reason is: there is a hard limit (set to ten thousand by default, though that can be increased via registry hacks) of the number of GDI objects that can be outstanding in a process -- not application domain, note -- and the garbage collector might not get around to finalizing resources faster than they are being leaked. Managed memory allocations produce *collection pressure* but there is no corresponding *finalization pressure*.

> The purpose of garbage collection is to eliminate these kinds of requirements.

It is not. The purpose of garbage collection is to emulate an environment with arbitrarily much memory.

> One of the main purposes of `IDisposable` is to allow a class to clean up unmanaged resources in resource-limited environments.

This is correct.

> If you do not call the `Dispose()` method, the unmanaged resources of the class will be cleaned up once the object is finialized and disposed during garbage collection.

This is sometimes correct; it is correct for GDI objects. It is a good practice for classes which hold on to unmanaged resources to implement finalization semantics as a backstop; an extra layer of protection for people who follow the bad advice given in the accepted answer.  **You should not rely on finalizers to save you from your mistakes; you should dispose of your resources.**

You should only rely on a finalizer to deal with crazy exceptional situations. Consider for example:

```
Brush myBrush = MakeMeABrush();
DoSomethingWithBrush(myBrush);
myBrush.Dispose();
```

Suppose a thread abort exception is thrown *after* the allocation of the brush but *before* the assignment to myBrush.  No combination of `try-catch-finally` will enable you to clean up that brush via `Dispose`; you'll have to rely upon the finalizer. That's what the finalizer is for: the *completely crazy* situations where you *cannot* dispose yourself. **It is not an excuse to be sloppy.**

> If you "must" call dispose and you do not know if the brush instance is a "system-" or a "normal-" brush then you will have to use a try...catch block.

Though this is again, technically correct, it misses the point completely. **If you are in a situation where you do not know whether or not you own the brush then you have a bug in your program design**. Do not paper over your bugs with a `try-catch` block!  Fix the bug!

This situation is common to all explicitly-managed resources: **the entity which provides the resource and the entity which consumes the resource are responsible for clearly documenting which of the two owns cleaning up the resource**.  If you don't know whether you own the brush that you've been given or not then **someone isn't doing a task they were responsible to do**, namely, **preventing that situation from ever arising**.

If the contract you decide upon is that the entity which provides the resource is responsible for cleaning it up later then *your consumer shouldn't be disposing of the brush at all*, because that is breaking the contract; the producer will clean that up if it needs to.

If the contract you decide upon is that both the producer and consumer are going to free the resource, then the consumer must call `Clone` on *every* brush passed in to ensure that they have a safely disposable resource, and that the producer continues to own a valid resource as well.

If, most likely, the contract you decide upon is that the entity which is consuming the resource is responsible for cleaning it up later then **the provider is required to always hand you a brush that you can safely dispose**, and is required to **not** dispose the resource itself.  Since the *provider* knows whether they made the brush themselves or got it from the system, the provider must call `Clone()` on system brushes to obtain a brush that can be safely disposed, and then pass *that* to the consumer.

But the contract "no one cleans it up and we hope for the best" is a pretty poor contract.

> It is not needed to call `Dispose()` on `SystemBrushes` and `SystemPens` because the GDI+ Library will take care of these resources.

This explanation is an explanation that doesn't actually explain anything. The reason why it is illegal to dispose of one of these brushes is because **the lifetime of the brush is equal to the lifetime of the appdomain**.

> The Remarks section of the class will make note of if there is a requirement to call the Dispose method.

This statement is false.  You should make the assumption that it is always necessary to `Dispose` an `IDisposable` resource unless you have good reason to believe otherwise. The absence of a line in the documentation is not evidence that disposing is unnecessary.

To end on a positive note:

> If I have a graphic-intensive application or class then I will cache instances of the pens and brushes I need. I use them throughout the life of the application or class.

This is a good practice. If the number of brushes and pens created is relatively small and the same ones are being used over and over again, then it makes good sense to cache them permanently. Since their lifetimes are to the end of the program there is no need to dispose them. In this case we are not disposing the garbage because *it's not garbage*; it's useful. GDI objects that are *not* cached should of course still be disposed. Again, pursuing a caching strategy is not an excuse to engage in poor practices.

Comment: While I agree that murky ownership is a sign of poor design, it should be noted that some of the WinForms classes have precisely that problem baked into them.  For example, who owns the `Font` associated with a `Button` or the `Image` associated with a `PictureBox`?  How can one tell?

Comment: @supercat: I am not an expert on Windows Forms by any means but it was my understanding that a button owns its resources, and the button's container in turn owns it. When the outermost containing object is disposed then all the sub-objects are recursively disposed. But like I said, I am not an expert; if an expert on this were to weigh in I would be happy to learn more.

Comment: If a button owned its resources, then assigning the `.Font` property should logically cause the previously-assigned `Font` to be `Dispose`d, but that doesn't happen.  The `.Font` case is particularly weird because from what I can tell, *nobody* needs to own the `Font` assigned to a control's `.Font` property; one can call `Dispose` the `Font` at any time--even before assigning the property, and the control will be oblivious to it.  Perhaps there should have been a separate non-`IDisposable` class for control fonts?

Comment: Of greater importance than the particulars of `WinForms`, however, is a broader issue: is there any standard convention for FrameWork documentation to indicate the cases where object ownership is transferred and the cases where it is not?  I would consider such information very important, but the only way I've been able to find out such things is via experimentation.

Comment: @supercat: You are wrong about `.Font` assignments not triggering disposal.  Hans Passant discusses this in response to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5148476/18192 .  Checking the Control.cs in the .Net reference source code confirms that Hans is correct; there is code to ensure the `Font` is disposed in both the `OnFontChanged` function and in the `Font` setter.  These `dispose` calls don't always happen (e.g., if you assign a Font over itself, it won't dispose it, since it's obviously in use).

Comment: @Brian: Is the `Font` which a control disposes the same `Font` object which is passed in?  I don't think it is.  I think `Control` creates a new `Font` object based on the one which is passed in, but its `.Font` property returns a reference to the last thing stored there.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for your answer. I take your point that not knowing where a resource came from may be bug. However sometimes we need to use 3rd-party libraries that don't always behave in the way you described - and so to keep GDI objects under control you do have to dispose of resources who's origin you're uncertain about.

Comment: @AMissico: The lack of a compiler error stems from the fact that, in the general case it is not possible for the compiler to know which reference to an object will be used last.  If `IDisposable` were included in the core of the Framework, rather than being an afterthought, such things would be handled better.  As it is, however, code which allows objects that implement `IDisposable` to be abandoned without `Dispose` having been called on them, and which doesn't have a good reason for doing so, should be considered broken.

Comment: @AMissico: Your faith in the compiler is touching but completely misplaced. Think about it: if there were a way for *the compiler* to know when the object should be disposed then there would also be a way for *the runtime* to know that, since the runtime has more information than the compiler. Since by definition we have `IDisposable` for precisely those situations where *the resource must be cleaned up manually because the runtime is going to do a bad job of it*, clearly the *compiler* cannot tell you where you're supposed to dispose. If it could then **we wouldn't need `IDisposable`!**

Comment: @AMissico: You also continue to use "requirement" in a deeply unfortunate way. You are basically saying that there is no *requirement* that the programmer choose to write a program using best practices; a programmer can instead choose to write sloppy, dangerous, brittle code. That is in a sense correct; no programming language has been invented yet that prevents the developer from writing bad code. But to *advocate* worst practices on the basis of "you can get away with them" does your fellow programmers a disservice.

Comment: @DavidGardiner: If you use buggy, poorly-designed third party libraries then yes, you have to work around their bugs and design flaws. My advice: don't use such libraries.

Comment: @AMissico: The C# compiler team and the R#er team have aligned but non-identical goals -- not to mention scope of work, budgets and business models. As a former member of the C# compiler team now working on a third party analyzer that, among other things, finds defects such as these, I could discuss the differences at length, and I have; see my articles on the nature of C# compiler warnings for details. Briefly though: R#er can afford to do a *deeper*, more *expensive* analysis that is *more likely to be wrong*. Hence: no such feature in the C# compiler. Do not rely on the lack of a warning!

Comment: @AMissico: I'm not turning this into a debate about anything; this is not a debating site.  I'm correcting your errors and warning other readers to not follow your example. This would be a good time to stop being defensive and take the opportunity to learn what the best practices are here. (And those best practices include your suggestion of building a cache to improve performance; I note however that *a cache without an expiration policy is a possible source of resource leaks*, so be careful.)

Comment: @AMissico: Your statement is correct. Brushes and pens are managed objects which hold on to unmanaged resources, namely, GDI handles, and which are a strictly limited resource; there may be no more than ten thousand per process, by default. Therefore it is a best practice to dispose of them when you're done with them.

Comment: @EricLippert; I am fully aware of the best practices of using and implementing IDisposable in classes and derived classes. I am defensive because I don't appreciate your critiquing the answer because it is not "perfect". With the flurry of answers and comments at the time, the poster got his answer. I wrote specifically leaving out details, because the question showed a working knowledge of IDisposable. If you do not like specifics, fix the answer. I never bothered fixing the answer because the poster got his answer and other question/answers handled the subject better.

Comment: @AMissico: Your answer is not only "not perfect"--it is fundamentally wrong in a number of major aspects including the first sentence.  When .NET was in its infancy, its creators expected, perhaps naïvely, that the garbage collector and `Object.Finalize()` would suffice to take care of object cleanup.  Nice in theory, perhaps, but *things can't and don't work that way*.  Some objects that implement `IDisposable` can simply be abandoned without causing trouble, but others require types of cleanup *which `Finalize` is incapable of performing*, and will cause major problems if they're abandoned.

Comment: @AMissico: Well then you probably should learn to appreciate constructive criticism without reacting defensively; doing so has helped me greatly in my career and it might help you too. Your attitude that bad is good enough and details don't matter might also bear adjustment. I'm not criticizing your answer because it is *imperfect*, I'm criticizing it because it is actively harming the world. It's easily found via web search and contains really, really bad advice that people who don't know better -- and why would they be looking for advice if they knew better? -- might take.

Comment: @supercat; >>"including the first sentence.<< No. Consider if a field in a form is required, you must enter a value. There is no choice. It is not a best practice to enter a value. You cannot decide you don't feel like entering a value. You must enter a value. Therefore, calling Dispose is not required. There is no argument regarding my statement. Now if you want to talk about best pratices and IDisposable code/design patterns, then we can have an intelligent discussion and we may both learn from it.

Comment: @AMissico: Different languages have different idioms related to necessity, but in English a statement that "there is no requirement to do X" implies that X is generally not necessary, and is very different from a statement that "there is not always a requirement to do X".  Consider the statement "There is no requirement to stop at stop signs".  Such a statement could be justified on two grounds: (1) there are some intersections in the US where a stop sign will have below it a sign reading "Right turn no stop".  If one wants to make a right turn, one needn't stop.  Also...

Comment: ...(2) at most intersections, at most times of the day, one could ignore a stop sign and drive straight through at speed, and have a 90%+ chance of getting away unscathed.  One could accurately say that "There is not always a requirement to stop at stop signs", but that is (at least in English) very different from saying "there is no requirement to stop at stop signs".

Comment: @supercat; that is the difference between me and you. The law requires you to stop at Stop signs so I do so. When the specifications states requirements, I implement the requirements. There is no question. This is not an argument about the symatics of the work "require".

Answer (score 5):

When you are finished with a Graphics object that you create, you must dispose of it by calling its Dispose method. (This rule is true for many different GDI+ objects.) Don't keep it around for a rainy day because it won't be valid later. You must, must, must dispose of it when you are finished with it. If you don't, it could result in image corruption, memory usage issues, or worse yet, international armed conflict. So, please dispose of all Graphics objects properly.

If you create a Graphics object within an event, you really need to dispose of it before exiting that event handler. There is no guarantee that the Graphics object will still be valid in a later event. Besides, it's easy to re-create another Graphics object at any time.

Got from here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596518431-01-18.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you always should Dispose of brushes when you can and not leave it up to the garbage collector.  While GDI will eventually get around to taking care of that stuff (assuming the library gets shut down properly), there's no telling when that may be.  In fact, my understanding is that brush handles stick around for the long-term.  Over the course of a long-running application, you're looking at a *de facto* memory leak.  Sure, in a small application that won't run for long, or in one that only rarely creates brushes, you can let the system handle it, but that strikes me as sloppy.

As a general rule, whenever I create a brush I do so in a using statement.  That automatically calls dispose on the brush without having to worry about it.  As an added bonus, since you create the brush inside the statement you know that it's not a predefined brush.  Any time you create and use a non-predefined brush, wrap the block in a using and you don't have to worry about it at all.  In fact, you don't even need to explicitly call Dispose, since the block will do so even in the case of an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is,.. if you create it, either delegate responsibility to clean up or clean the objects up yourselves.  You can create GDI resource "leaks" by letting things hang in the garbage collector.  They may eventually be cleaned up, but they are not doing any good hanging there.  i.e. if you don't call "close" or Dispose on opened files, the file's remain locked until the GC "gets around to it"

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think you can assume that the lifetime (and the disposal) of the predefined brushes and pens is not your app's responsibility and will be handled by the system.

In short: don't call Dispose on the predefined stuff. :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to avoid - my question is how to know if calling Dispose() is ok or not. I'm interested if there's anything better than calling Dispose() inside a try/catch, because I'd prefer to avoid the 'cost' of having an exception thrown.

Comment: @Whoever: Why the downvote? **Lzcd** is correct. You can verify through Microsoft's source code or *.NET Reflector*.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing come in mind is to have a practice do not use System pens/brushes as parameters to methods.

Comment: Or adapt a policy that if an object is passed in the caller needs to `Dispose()` it appropriately. If the caller got the object, it knows whether or not it got it from a system brush or not and can appropriately include or omit the `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, using Reflector I see that the System.Drawing.Pen and System.Drawing.SolidBrush classes have a private field named 'immutable'.

This field appears to be set to true when the object refers to a system-defined resource, so you could use reflection to carefully check the value of this field to decide whether to call Dispose() on it.