# Windows Form Fonts Questions Part 1

Tags: winforms, fonts, dispose

I have some user controls in a windows form. I wonder

1. if i set the `Font` property of the main form, will its child get a) a copy of the new `Font`, or b) a reference to the new `Font`, or c) nothing?
2. Does a font need to be disposed? For example, can I do the following code safely?

   form.Font = new Font(...);
3. Will a font get disposed automatically when the parent (`Form` or `UserControl`) is disposed?

Thanks,
Gilbert

Comment: part 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149220/windows-form-fonts-questions-part-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Both.  The Font property is its own .NET object.  Winforms however caches the native Windows font, they are fairly expensive to create.  The .NET wrapper object is quite small.
2. Yes.  The code is fine, the Font property setter already disposes the previously assigned font.
3. Yes, it is disposed by the UserControl.  Which in turn is automatically disposed by its parent.

Comment: Some developers got caught with this, so the wording shall be different here:
1. When Font property of the form is set, its child controls get neither copy of System.Drawing.Font object nor the reference. A form creates an unmanaged handle. A child grabs that handle through subscription to a particular event. Font property getter returns parent’s Font if control’s Font has not been set.      
3. Font object assigned to Font property is NOT getting disposed when the control is disposed. So you can create a single Font object and assign it to multiple dynamically created/disposed controls.

Comment: That's a completely different answer.  You should post it, SO users will vote it up when they agree.

Answer (score 1):

1. When `Font` property of the main form is set, its child controls get neither deep copy of `System.Drawing.Font` object nor the reference to it. On assignment, parent form creates unmanaged font object handle. All child controls are subscribed to parent’s FontChanged event so they have a chance to grab this handle and use it later for text rendering. `Font` property getter of a control returns parent’s Font if control’s Font property has not been set explicitly (or default font).
2. Windows Forms does what is logically expected with any other property: When you assign a `System.Drawing.Font` object to `Font` property of a control, a previously assigned `System.Drawing.Font` object gets finalized and garbage-collected if no more references to it remain in your application. So yes, you can do this safely.
3. `System.Drawing.Font` object assigned to `Font` property of a control is NOT getting disposed when the control is disposed, or another `System.Drawing.Font` is assigned to `Font` property. So you are safe to create a single `System.Drawing.Font` object and assign it to multiple controls, which are created and disposed dynamically. You are also free to create multiple fonts and assign them to a control periodically to create some visual effects.  Internal unmanaged font handles are managed by Windows Forms.

Comment: Via what mechanism do children get this handle, and what can they do with it given that drawing methods expect a `Font` object rather than a GDI handle?

Comment: Font property setter calls OnFontChanged virtual method. This method calls OnParentFontChanged virtual method on each child control. This is how child objects get the handle. Indeed, drawing methods of managed controls expect Font object, and Font property getter provides parent's Font object if control's Font has not been set. But some Controls are managed wrappers around WIN32 windows, and by default WIN32 paints window text using a font that shall be set by means of this handle.

Comment: MSDN shows `ParentFontChanged` as just taking an EventArgs.  I don't see any font handle there.  The parent object exposes a `Font` property, but child controls don't seem to draw just fine whether or not it has a valid handle.  Are controls caching the font handle somewhere else, or do the normal draw routines create font handles every time they draw and dispose them afterward, or do they use the handle in `Font` if it exists and create/dispose a temporary font handle if needed, or what?

Comment: After you send WM_SETFONT mesaage to a native Window and specify HFONT handle as a parameter, this font becomes a default font for current window. I didn't investigate this matter in that deep level, but I suppose that Windows Forms does just that.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the child form is already open, no it won't get a copy.

   - To expand a little on this if the child form does inherit the parents font. I don't think that changing the parents font would effect the child font after the window is already open.
2. The garbage collector should take care of it.
3. yes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the Font property of a control is used to determine the font settings to use when drawing the control, but the GDI Font associated with that property isn't used to do the drawing.  A control won't care if the Font that's assigned to its Font property is disposed after it's assigned, or even before it's assigned.  The control is clearly capable of using some hidden aspects of the Font object which are available even after it is Disposed to determine the appropriate attributes of the font, but I don't know whether it

1. Uses the supplied Font object, if not disposed, or else creates its own temporary font object each time it has to draw something and disposes the temporary object immediately thereafter.

   Uses the supplied Font object, if not disposed, or else creates its own private font object which it will dispose of when either the Font property is reassigned or the control is disposed.

   Copies the font family, size, etc. from the Font object when the Font property is assigned, and does everything with its private temporary or persistent Font objects it creates itself.

   Copies the font family, size, etc. from the assigned Font object whenever it's necessary to draw something.

The control certainly keeps a reference to the passed-in font object, if for no other reason than to supply it to the Font property getter.  I have no idea, though, whether it's better to dispose the Font after assigning it, or whether it's better to keep a copy of the Font in the form and dispose it when the Form itself is disposed.