# Setting Font of a Textbox increments GDI HFONT Handles

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, fonts, gdi

We have a dynamic control creation allowing the user to configure task-oriented GUI's by himself. Some WinForms controls seem to handle unmanaged handles differently to others. The best example for the issue is the TextBox:

As soon as a text box instance Font property is set, a new GDI handle is created even if the font is the same as in another text box instance. The same stands for setting the BackColor which creates a HBRUSH handle.

If you have a rich user interface with a lot of controls, the windows limit of 10000 handles per process can easily be reached.

One work-around is to set the font using WM_SETFONT and keeping handle creation under control but that leads to other problems such as the text box won't resize to the font.

To view the GDI handles, we use GDIView from Nir-Soft. An example code with three textboxes and two buttons would look like that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Used for the work-around
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject([In]IntPtr hObject);

    // Used for the work-around
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    internal const int WM_SETFONT = 0x0030;

    private class FontFactory
    {
        private static Dictionary<Font, IntPtr> _fonts = new Dictionary<Font, IntPtr>();
        public static void SetFont(Font font, IntPtr controlHandle)
        {

            IntPtr fontHandle;
            if (!_fonts.TryGetValue(font, out fontHandle))
            {
                fontHandle = font.ToHfont();
                _fonts[font] = fontHandle;
            }

            SendMessage(controlHandle, WM_SETFONT, fontHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use these lines to reproduce the problem - Will increment HFONTS by 3
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 10.5f);
        textBox1.Font = font;
        textBox2.Font = font;
        textBox3.Font = font;

        // This will reduce the number of handles but does not resize the text boxes
        // Increments HFONTS by only one
        /*          
        FontFactory.SetFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", 12.5f), textBox1.Handle);
        FontFactory.SetFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", 12.5f), textBox2.Handle);
        FontFactory.SetFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", 12.5f), textBox3.Handle);
        */
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls.Remove(textBox3);
        textBox3.Dispose();
        textBox3 = null;

        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

I hope I could well enough explain the issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't really see the problem/issue? a textbox needs an HFONT & backround brush, it makes sense they maintain their own - its cheap to do so and does not require some kind of shared backing pool.  What specifically are you doing that the 10k limit is a concern?  Its certainly not something you would normally need to even consider.

Comment: I'd hate to be the user confronted with a single process with 10,000 controls/windows

Comment: You need to dispose of all GDI resources you create when done with them. Disposing of the TextBoxes is not enough, afaik.

Comment: We really have all those controls active and alive, not on a single view but in different views. If we'd dispose views if not visible, the performance would not be accepted by the customers. I don't think that it's okay that a control is the owner of given handles - the owner should be the caller therefore an incrementation of handles when a property is set is not desired.

@MickyD : it's not 10000 controls, its 10000 GDI related properties of controls set to custom values not matching the default values

TaW : The dispose code from above correctly decrements the handle count

Comment: If I read [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148476/windows-form-fonts-questions-part-1),  than the behavior is described different than you write it here. I don't know who is wrong. Usually WinForms should do a lot of optimizations when I read thing answer.

Comment: Consider using the various **Grid Controls** instead of dynamically creating so many TextBoxes.

Comment: @xMRi - It could be that my understanding isn't totally correct, the example above was used to empirically test the behavior. I have to add that not all controls behave the same. The font example doesn't stand for Labels, for instance. If you'd replace the textboxes in the example above, the GDI HFONT count would be correct.

Comment: I'm using your words.   The only time we native programmers ever ran into the GDI resource exhaustion problem is due to a bug on our part.  To run into it deliberately by design is just ridiculous