# Unexpected results from Graphics.FillRectangle()

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to make a little 15x15 playing grid, and drawing the solid outline rectangles side-by-side is working just fine, however when I try to call FillRectangle() to fill the aforementioned cells the results are .. Not quite what I expected.. I think it's easier if I just show you..

[image: filled grid]

Here's the code

```
//Draw grid now since InitGrid() is done
using (Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics())
{
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Beige);

            int y = new int();
            List<Rectangle> rect = new List<Rectangle>();

            foreach (Cell cell in pGrid.cells)
            {
                rect.Add(new Rectangle(cell.Point.X, cell.Point.Y, 18, 18));
                formGraphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect[y]);
                formGraphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect[y++]);
            }
        }
```

Also an extra question, since I am using a `using` code block do I still have to call `Dispose()` on the `Pen` and `Graphics`?

Comment: What is the first question? You have not asked one! The answer to the first is no, the GC takes care of this for you...

Comment: Well I want to fill each individual "rectangle" with beige not cover the whole grid with a big beige block, I thought I was doing that with my code right now but it seems I am not.

Answer (score 3):

The differences in the "covered area" are caused by `DrawRectangle` using a `Pen` which has a thickness of 1px, and 0.5px of that is added to the outer edges of the rectangle, and then rounded "to the bottom-right". These bottom-right borders are then overwritten by the next cell's `FillRectangle`.

You could use a border thickness of 2, which would cause the border to be 2 pixels larger than the filled area, and thus appear 1px thick on each side.

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
```

This only works if there is actual space between the cells to show the borders in. If there is no room for the borders you'll have to either shrink your cell size or grow the grid itself.

Another solution (since you mention the outlines are fine) is to first call `FillRectangle` and then `DrawRectangle`.

Also a `using` around the pen and brush won't hurt. Note that you can also use the static `Pens.Black` (unless you're going for the solution of a 2px thick border) and `Brushes.Beige`.

Comment: Sorry about all the editing, I'm trying to get the story straight but I keep discovering new things about the question I need to incorporate :P

Comment: No problems with your editing, you've given a very thorough answer and you've given me a few options to consider as well :). Regarding the `using` block, I was under the impression that everything within that code block would have it's `Dispose()` method called after block execution, so wouldn't that then include the pen/brushes?

Comment: @OverlyExcessive Only the object within the `using` block is disposed. By explicitly disposing the `Pen` and `Brush` you're releasing resources as soon as possible. Not disposing them means the garbage collector would clean up "some time later". `Pen` and `Brush` are not associated with one `Graphics` object (try moving the code up outside the `using` block).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200753/avoiding-disposing-system-defined-pen-and-brush-instances for a long discussion about this.